# People are hungry while food is available

Tags: frostpunk

I've noticed, that sometimes in Frostpunk I have a warning about hungry (or even starving) people, even while I have processed (cooked) food available. When I've tried to find those hungry people, they were at work, in the fighting arena or doing anything other than actually feeding themselves.

I usually build only one cookhouse, since it is so efficient and I can usually process easily all raw food into the processed one - but is the cookhouse the problem here? Do people go there to eat and my workaholics were starving because they couldn't find a room?

Comment: Something I heard of (but haven't experienced) while watching Frostpunk playthroughs is that sometimes workers get stuck inside buildings, unable to actually walk to where they can eat. If you select one of the starving citizens, do they move at all?

Comment: @Zymus I thought that the worker position is purely cosmetic - for example various workplace start working exactly on the work start time well before people get there

Comment: it looks like it happens if the worker builds a building during off hours, they can get stuck. The worker is still assigned to the building, and the production hours start on time, not when the workers get there (I believe), which means that production is unaffected, but I believe hunger is on an individual level. Example, you have 600 citizens, 1200 raw food, 3000 rations, and only two people hungry (or starving). Why is it that all 598 others are fed, but not those two? Again, hasn't happened to me yet, but a search of "frostpunk stuck worker" seems to have more than a few results.

Answer (score 1):

I've found more information in the [Frostpunk Wiki](https://frostpunk.gamepedia.com/Food)

> Frostpunk's citizens have a priority list, and eating isn't very high on that list unless they are starving. Priorities are, from highest to lowest:
>
> - build Streets,
> - build Buildings,
> - dismantle buildings,
> - go to work,
> - go to eat,
> - go to work.
>
> If a person is trying to eat, but there is a task of higher priority on their to-do list, they will forgo eating and instead go to complete the task you've set for them. "Go to work" is listed twice, because its priority changes depending on whether someone is eating on the way to/from work or whether they were ripped from a different task

Further on, the Cookhouse has a limit of 250 people:

> **People eat Food Rations at the Cookhouse, regardless of whether it is turned on or off, heated, or even connected to roads**, so long as you have Food Rations available in your inventory. People must walk to and from the cookhouse to eat. Furthermore, Cookhouses have an internal queue that limits how many citizens they can serve. This queue holds approximately 250 people at one time, per Cookhouse. This means that if you have too many people queuing for food at the same time, they may forgo eating even if you have enough food to serve them.

So the soulution seems to be "reduce building in the off-time and build more cookhouses" (and possibly leave the off)